# Inequality for positive definite matrices of specific type

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite

We call a matrix *good* if it is symmetric positive definite with all its eigenvalues below $1$ .

Assume that we have a *good* matrix $B$.
How to show that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\left(\mathbb{I} - (\mathbb{I}-B)^n\right)^2\prec nB$$

I know that, given a *good* matrix $B$, the matrices $(\mathbb{I}-B)$ and $(\mathbb{I} - (\mathbb{I}-B)^n)$ are *good* as well. So, it is easy to show that 
$$\left(\mathbb{I} - (\mathbb{I}-B)^n\right)^2\prec I $$

But $\left(\mathbb{I} - (\mathbb{I}-B)^n\right)^2\prec nB$ does seem to be more difficult to prove.

Comment: What does your wavy inequality sign denote?

Comment: @JohnHughes, $A \succeq 0$ for positive definite $A$. $A \preceq B$ if $B - A\succeq 0$ is positive definite.

Comment: @John Hughes It is what is called "Loewner order" (http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/W12/NotesMatrices.pdf)

Comment: I thought that was what OP meant; but other folks use inequality symbols like $A \ge 0$ to mean "all entries of $A$ are nonnegative," and I wanted to be sure to get it right. Also: the notation used actually refers to positive SEMI-definite matrices (at least according to Wikipedia); positive definite is denoted without the partial-equals sign. That, too, was puzzling me.

Comment: @JohnHughes, you're right. Now I edited the notation in the statement accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $Q$ is orthogonal and diagonalizes $B$. Then 
$$
Q'BQ = D
$$
is diagonal (where the prime means 'transpose'), with all diagonal entries strictly between 0 and 1, and each column of $v$ is a unit eigenvector of $B$.

It turns out that such eigenvectors are also eigenvectors of $I - B$ (with eigenvalues $1-c$, where $c$ is the corresponding eigenvalue in $B$), hence of $(I - B)^n$, and hence of $(I - (I-B)^n)$, and hence of $(I - (I- B)^n)^2$. In short: $Q$ also diagonalizes the matrix you're looking at.

I believe (but I might be wrong -- kinda early in the morning) that in the $Q$ basis, your matrix looks like
$$
(I - (I - D)^n)^2
$$
Now all you have to do is check that for each diagonal entry $c$ of $D$, you have
$$
(1 - (1-c)^n)^2 \le nc
$$

which is presumably either false or a not-too-hard calculus problem. I leave that part to you.

I'm a little uncertain about the less-than-or-equal vs less-than matter; I *suspect* that $A \preceq 0$ really means that $A$ is positive *semi*definite, but I can't be sure of that. Anyhow, you can decide which one it is, and then you can do the appropriate calculus problem.

Comment: Yes, $(1 - (1-c)^n)^2 \le nc$ is true for all $c\in [0,1]$. I just did not know how to extend it to the case of matrices. Thanks a lot!